# getCellEditorValue() of CellEditor.java is Only Called When the Cell is Clicked

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Consider the following Jtable, and more precisely the first column which has a JComboBox in it:

[image]

When I try to save the value of the first JComboBox (the one that has "auth2" as its value) without clicking on it first, when I check the database, I find an empty String.

However, when I click on it first and then save, I get the right value stored in the databse.

Using the debugger, I found out that the method `getCellEditorValue()` of `CellEditor.java` is only called when you click on the JComboBox itself first.

This explains why in the database, I get the right value when I click on the JComboBox first and when I don't click on it, I get an empty String.

So my question is, is there a way to call the `getCellEditorValue()` method every time I save, regardless of whether or not I click on the JComboBox?

Thank you

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is create a JFrame with a JTable that uses a combo box as an editor. Then add a button to the frame. When you click the button get the value from the TableModel of the selected row in the table. The editor will have nothing to do with the code in your ActionListener added to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the right value when I click on the JComboBox first and when I don't click on it, I get an empty String.

You should NOT try to access a value from the combo box. The combo box is shared as an editor for all rows in the table.

> is there a way to call the getCellEditorValue() method every time I save

Data is stored in the `TableModel`, not the combo box.

You can use the `getValueAt(…)` method of the `JTable` or `TableModel` at any time to get the value from the model.

Note: it is possible (depending on what you are doing) that the data has not been saved from the editor to the `TableModel`. If this is the case then check out: [JTable stop cell editing without user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397785/jtable-stop-cell-editing-without-user-click/38399315#38399315) for solutions.

Comment: Thanks for you time. The problem is that the part of the code where the values are saved  is inside `getCellEditorValue()` of `CellEditor.java`. And this method seems to only get called when I click on the cell. So the only way for me to save the value is through this method. This is why I'm looking for a way to call it even when I don't click on the cell itself.

Comment: No, that is NOT the problem. There is no reason for you to deal with the editor when trying to access data in the table.  I have given you the proper solution.

Comment: You are right about me not fully understanding how editor works and I appreciate your time and patience. I had to change a lot from the already existing code to make it work but your advice helped me a lot to reach the solution. Thanks again for helping me out.